# 'SerialStream' does not name a type

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, libserial

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.
I want to use `libSerial` for project like described [here](https://github.com/crayzeewulf/libserial/blob/master/examples/read_port.cpp).
I installed the library using `sudo apt-get install libserial-dev`.

I've written a little program (well, it's not really a program):

```
#include "SerialStream.h"
#include <iostream>

#define PORT "/dev/ttyUSB0"

SerialStream ardu;

using namespace std;
using namespace LibSerial;
```

But the compiler says: `‘SerialStream’ does not name a type`

Any help?

EDIT:
After placing the `SerialStream ardu` after the namespace-line the problem is even more strange:

```
g++ main.cpp -o ArduCom
/tmp/ccNzzINg.o: In Funktion `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x7a): not defined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStream::Open(std::string, std::_Ios_Openmode)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x12d): not defined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStream::SetBaudRate(LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::BaudRateEnum)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x181): not defined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStream::SetCharSize(LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::CharSizeEnum)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1d5): not defined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStream::SetParity(LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::ParityEnum)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x229): not defined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStream::SetNumOfStopBits(short)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x27d): not defined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStream::SetFlowControl(LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::FlowControlEnum)'
/tmp/ccNzzINg.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE[_ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE]+0x48): not defined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::showmanyc()'
/tmp/ccNzzINg.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE[_ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE]+0x50): not defined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::xsgetn(char*, long)'
/tmp/ccNzzINg.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE[_ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE]+0x58): not defined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::underflow()'
/tmp/ccNzzINg.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE[_ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE]+0x68): not defined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::pbackfail(int)'
/tmp/ccNzzINg.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE[_ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE]+0x70): not defined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::xsputn(char const*, long)'
/tmp/ccNzzINg.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE[_ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE]+0x78): not defined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::overflow(int)'
```

Comment: Did you try placing `SerialStream ardu;` after the `using namespace LibSerial;` statement?

Comment: @Galik; sry, typo, does not change the problem...

Comment: @PEAR Your edit doesn't make anything clearer? Just try what I've told you to do, or write `LibSeria::SerialStream ardu;`.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the comment first...

Comment: @PEAR see here please, how to fix that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: I'm not sure what to do... I tried the official example of the lib and the same error occured. Is this a bug in the library?

Comment: @PEAR What's the command used to link your executable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87105/discussion-between-pear-and--).

Comment: @pesr Nope, imprrove your qurstion plesse.

Comment: The problem is not worse, its fixed. What you have now is a *different* problem. :) You need to add the library to your link command.

Comment: 'Is this a bug in the library?' I cannot believe comments like that.

Comment: @john: Well, I don't really assume that there is a bug in the library... but in my case the official example did not work.

Comment: @Galik: How can I do this?

Comment: `g++ main.cpp -lSerial -o ArduCom` at a wild guess

Comment: Assuming you *installed* the library to a default place then `g++ main.cpp -o ArduCom -lserial` may be enough. Otherwise you may have to specify where the library is using the `-L` switch: `g++ main.cpp -o ArduCom -Wl,-rpath,/path/to/library/folder -L/path/to/library/folder -lserial`.

Comment: @Galik: Would you please post this as a comment so the thread can be closed

Comment: @PEAR I assume you meant post it as an *answer*. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have defined an object of type `SerialStream` from the namespace `LibSerial` without properly *qualifying* it:

```
#include "SerialStream.h"
#include <iostream>

#define PORT "/dev/ttyUSB0"

SerialStream ardu; // error this type is unqualified

using namespace std;
using namespace LibSerial;
```

There are a number of ways to *qualify* the type. One is by placing the definition *after* the *using declaration* of the *namespace* the type is defined in:

```
#include "SerialStream.h"
#include <iostream>

#define PORT "/dev/ttyUSB0"

using namespace std;
using namespace LibSerial;

// qualified by the compiler searching through the
// declared namespaces and finding it in `namespace LibSerial`.

SerialStream ardu;
```

Another way is to *qualify* the typename explicitly as belonging in a specific namespace:

```
LibSerial::SerialStream ardu; // fully qualifies name
```

Having done that, your second problem is that the compiler needs to know where the `libserial` library is located in the *file system* in order to be able to link to it.

Assuming you installed the library to a default place then this maybe enough:

```
g++ main.cpp -o ArduCom -lserial
```

Otherwise you may have to specify where the library is using the -L switch:

```
g++ main.cpp -o ArduCom -Wl,-rpath,/path/to/library/folder -L/path/to/library/folder -lserial
```

The `libserial` library is built using [Autotools](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Autotools-Introduction.html) so, if you built and installed it from source it provides linking instructions as part of the *install* process.

The instructions are somewhat like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /path/to/libserial/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the '-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the '-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to '/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```